# Help identify IC with erased label by using pin connections in the schematic

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, schematics, reverse-engineering

I am reversing a board which some of its IC labels are erased by the manufacturer. I've drowned its schematic in the picture below. The label-removed ICs in the schematic are IC5, IC8, and IC13 which are marked in the picture.
The table of resistor values is attached and all of the electrolyte capacitors are 10uF 50V except C9, C10.
I have also attached the pictures of the ICs on the board.

The board connects to a motherboard by a 3*32 pin connector which is shown by a rectangle sign with its number in the schematic. I found a text about this board that says the board's job is analog processing of values measured by other motherboard's cards.

From the schematic, I guess that IC13 is a kind of switch-mode power supply and IC5 is maybe a quad digital to analog converter.
I searched in datasheets but still, I couldn't find any IC with input and output pins accorded to the schematic.

I hope you can help me to identify the marking code or the family of unknown ICs (IC5, IC8, IC13).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if any further information was needed.

Comment: I probably won't be able to answer your question, but I'm sure it would be helpful if you'd describe what this board is supposed to do. And if there are wires going in and out of the board, what those wires are doing and where they are connected in the schematic. Maybe also post a picture of the whole board and possibly the device it came from. Use the EDIT button to add this information to your original question.

Comment: Perhaps better on the Reverse Engineering Stack

Comment: it's usually written on the die

Comment: Hard to identify chips without some concept of function of board.

Comment: @MartinF 
I edited the schematic to be more clear. Unfortunately, I don't know what the board exactly do but it is connected to a motherboard by a 3*32 pin connector which is shown by small rectangles in the schematic.

Comment: Do you know if we have a kind of DAC like IC5 and a  switch-mode power supply like IC13?

Comment: IC2 says "4049" but pinout suggests a 74(LS?)245. 2 pins on IC5 (Vdd, Vss?) have no number. What are the resistor values, part numbers of D1 and D4 (Zener diodes) and what are the voltage ratings on the electrolytic caps? Can you show us a photo of the whole board?

Comment: IC5 might be an AD7549 https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7549.html#product-overview

Comment: IC8 might be an LTC1068? https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc1068.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott
You were right about the pinout of IC2 because IC2 is MC74HCT. I've corrected the label of IC2 and added pin numbers of IC5 and capacitors and zener diodes' part number in the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guesses are:-

IC13 - [RC4194](https://www.soemtron.org/downloads/disposals/rc4194db.pdf) Dual tracking Linear voltage regulators

[image]

IC5 - [AD7549](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7549.pdf) Dual 12 bit uP compatible DAC

[image]

IC8 - [LTC1068](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1068fc.pdf) Clock-Tunable Quad Second Order Filter Building Block

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test These ICs on the board and tell the final result.

Comment: I found 3 more ICs which have a similar pinout to [LTC1068](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1068fc.pdf). for IC8.

They are 
[LTC1064](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1064fb.pdf), [LTC1164](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1164fa.pdf), and [LTC1264](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1264fb.pdf).
Do you have any idea that which one of them is more probable to be IC8?

Comment: Pin 17 is tied V-, which I think rules out the LTC1264 and LTC1268 because they have fixed Clock-to-Center Frequency Ratios. On the LTC1064 and LTC1164 pin 17 tied to V- selects 100:1 ratio. The LTC1164 has lower supply current than the LTC1064, so that is one way you be might able to tell them apart.